# User and password

Tags: login, jessie-lite, password, user

I just installed Raspian Jessie lite date 4-10-17. All articles state the username and password are "pi" and "rasberry". These do not work. What is the correct user and password?

Comment: You need to use the correct password (and user name).  Computers are picky and do not tolerate spelling mistakes.

Comment: I think you will find its raspberry not rasberry...

Answer (score 19):

The username is "pi" and the password is "raspberry", you have misspelled the word "raspberry" by missing the p.

If you still have issues, I would try re-downloading, re-formatting, and doing it once more. I think you'll be fine after correcting the password entry.

It's good practice after logging in to [change](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md) the password of the user from the default.

Some users like to disable the pi account (especially if opened up to the internet) and create a new account and password to create minor security through obscurity, but it's not a replacement for following proper security practices.

[Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8555)

Comment: Thank you that was it. My vision must be going bad in my old age. I completely missed the spelling.

Answer (score 3):

just faced the same problem. everything written before is right, BUT : my installation had an english keyboard layout, which means, to input my "raspberry" pw i had to press "raspberrz"

Comment: Not tried it but [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/59528/how-do-i-set-the-dvorak-keyboard-layout-in-cmdline-txt#59535) suggests a way of setting the keyboard from `cmdline.txt` so you can login locally and run `raspi-config` to do it properly. Alternatively I believe you can enable `ssh` and log in in remotely and your keyboard layout will be translated for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a root access to your Rpi device, you can simply change the user's password, i.e. `passwd pi`. You can also remove the user's existing password (not recommended) by removing the 2nd field of the user account listed in /etc/shadow file (assuming shadow package is installed).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is 90% chance a keyboard layout problem.

Raspbian (lite) boots to tty and therefore uses a QWERTY (USA) kb layout by default.

so try rqspberry as password ;)

Comment: Please note that OP said it was actually a mistake while typing the password. See this answer: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/66028/42636

Answer (score -1):

If you are talking about root's password, its not set by default. Although whenever you write `su -` it asks for root password. It shouldn't ask in the first place if there isn't any.

So in order to solve this, write in terminal `sudo passwd root` and it will ask you twice to write password and you are good to go.